# How to handle Hibernate Search startup when elasticsearch backend is offline

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am facing following exception

> "org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable
>   to initialize IndexManager named
>   'com.dnow.tvs.domain.entity.epc.MyEntity"
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerGroupHolder.doCreateIndexManager(IndexManagerGroupHolder.java:198)
>   ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.10.5.Final.jar:5.10.5.Final]  at
>
> ... 37 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH400007: Elasticsearch request failed.
>   Request: GET  with parameters {}
>   Response: null
>
> ... 44 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
>
> org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.DefaultElasticsearchClient$1.onFailure(DefaultElasticsearchClient.java:123) ~[hibernate-search-elasticsearch-5.10.5.Final.jar:5.10.5.Final]

Its due to the fact that my elasticsearch server instance is not up and running.

So How can I handle the fallback when elasticsearch is not available at app startup or during the running application. How to gracefully recover this so that spring boot app can start seamlessly either elastic search is online or offline.

Here is my application properties.

```
>   jpa:
>     show-sql: true
>     properties:
>       hibernate:
>         search:
>           default:
>             indexmanager: elasticsearch
>             elasticsearch:
>               required_index_status: yellow
>               index_schema_management_strategy: drop-and-create
>               host: http://127.0.0.1:9200
```

I do have gone through the official hibernate search documentation but could not identify the solution or configuration.

Please note my Hibernate Search version is 5.10 and elasticsearch version is 5.6.16.

I really appreciate the help. Let me know any other info required.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable Hibernate Search completely, you can simply set `hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners` to `false`, as [explained in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#_enabling_hibernate_search).

If you want to disable Hibernate Search only when the Elasticsearch cluster is down at startup, then there is no such feature in Hibernate Search. However, you can do that yourself.

[This section of the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties) mentions that you can register a `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` bean that is able to customize the properties. I suppose you could register such a bean, and in the implementation you would to send a request to the Elasticsearch cluster yourself, decide if it's up or down based on the response, and set `hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners` to `true` or `false` depending on that. Be sure to use a reasonable timeout in your request, though, because this will be executed each time you start your application.

If you want to disable the calls to the Elasticsearch cluster *during startup*, but still expect Hibernate Search to do its job when an entity is saved or a search is executed (because you expect the cluster to be back up again), that's another story.

I think your only option would be to set `index_schema_management_strategy` to `none`, as [explained in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-schema-management-strategy).

But it's not really a supported feature, more something that you can try and might work.

If it works, you will still have to somehow make sure your Elasticsearch schema is set up to what Hibernate Search expects. This might get easier once [HSEARCH-2366](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2366) is resolved, but right now there isn't any easy way to do that. Maybe spinning up another instance of your application with `index_schema_management_strategy` set to `create`?

Comment: index_schema_management_strategy = none did not worked. still on startup hibernate search indexManager tried to connect with elastic search server. This is what it tried to call and responded in stack trace
" Elasticsearch request failed.
Request: GET  with parameters {}
Response: null"

any thoughts?

Comment: There should be a way by which it tried to call a backup elasticsearch/lucene instance. or if there is some property by which if elastic search connection refused then disable the hibernate search. Offcourse my search micro service will not be able to search. but other micro services which are saving data and hibernate search only there to index the new records. so that services should not be impacted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I edited my answer to explain how to disable Hibernate Search completely... if that's what you mean? Regarding the error you get, are you sure you got that with Hibernate Search 5.10.5 and `hibernate.search.elasticsearch.default.index_schema_management_strategy = false`? It shouldn't trigger any request on startup since 5.10.2...

Comment: You can see my attached logs that I am using hibernate 5.10.5 .  There is no 'hibernate.search.elasticsearch.default.index_schema_management_strategy = false' , Only none, create, update, validate, drop-and-create ... supported here.

So yes your solution did not worked. Basically I want to skip elastic search connection setup when my micro service startsup only in case if elasticsearch service is down.  you can create this scenraio by first shutting down elastic search server and then start your hibernate search app. you will get Connection refused exception on app startup.

Comment: `hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners = false ` is not working, I already had tried that but still on app startup I am getting connection refused exception on creation of IndexManager.

Comment: `If you want to disable the calls to the Elasticsearch cluster during startup, but still expect Hibernate Search to do its job when an entity is saved or a search is executed, that's another story.` No I am not expecting Hibernate to do its Job. If My App was already running but somehow due to some reasons my elastic search cluster went down, in this case hibernate search will not be able to make index on new data insertion. ANd I am not expecting that my search service will work. on the other hand if elastic cluster was down before app startup then app failed to start. :-(

Comment: Yes that was a typo, I meant `hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners = none`. I updated my answer with a solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok that's almost comical at that point: I actually meeant `hibernate.search.elasticsearch.default.index_schema_management_strategy = none`.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I will apply these new suggestions and see what happened. will let you know the update. Thanks again

Comment: I am now able to handle startups. But as you said for using `hibernate.search.elasticsearch.default.index_schema_management_strategy = none` , It is not creating index on startup if elastic search cluster available. on the other hand create and update is not recommended for production. :-( What is best way for production to create index only for delta changes.

Comment: If you want to update your schema in production, the easiest way is to drop the indexes, let Hibernate Search create them and reindex everything. That's not always practical though, so if you can't do that the next easiest solution is to let Hibernate Search create the schema in a development environment, compare the current production schema and the new one, and manually create scripts to perform the upgrades. Similarly to what you would do with Hibernate ORM.